# Is using Mono on CentOS as good as using Microsoft IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono

I have a MVC project (web application) created using C# in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows. It is working perfectly on a Windows Server.

Now there is a requirement to shift the server from a Windows OS to CentOS.

I googled around to check how to run MVC project on CentOS and found that we can use mono.

But my query is, can we use it in the same way as we use IIS and Windows OS ?
I mean can I just take the project files from my current server (Windows Server 2012) and deploy them as it is on the new server (CentOS) and it will run as it is or do I have to make any programmatic changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in the past and it wasn't a straight compile and ready to go, I had to follow instructions to get it all migrated.

Here're couple of good resources to read as far as compatibility and migration:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/walkthrough-porting-asp-net-mvc-website-to-mono-2-6-1-and-mysql-on-linux-apache-porting-to-mono-part-3-of-3/